# How to ingest data from db in solr cloud

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solrconfig

I have succefully setup solr cloud using this article [SolrCloud – 2 Nodes Solr, 1 Node ZK Setup](http://SolrCloud%20%E2%80%93%202%20Nodes%20Solr,%201%20Node%20ZK%20Setup)
. Earlier i used solr and inside solr i created a folder name "TestSolr" with in that i have folder and files like conf,data,core.properties etc. Within conf folder i have created a file db-data-config.xml and put configuration with db and query which is injecting data in solr successfully.

```
    <dataConfig>
        <dataSource name="jdbc"  driver="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" url="jdbc:db2://100.10.10.10:50000/dbname" user="db2" password="db2"  />
            <document>

                <entity name="VIEWOne" pk="ID" query="select * from SERVEIT.VIEWONE"/>

</document>
</dataConfig>
```

There is also a file name managed-schema where i am giving fields entry.

But now working with solr cloud i have made two shards node1 and node2. Now not getting idea where to do db configuration and where to write query. Do i need to do it on both the shards or only in one. Does i need to make files db-data config.xml and managed schema as i made in solr. Not getting any idea of doing db configuration and executing above query. Please help

Answer (score 1):

when you use SolrCloud, it is not like standalone Solr. The conf files for collections that matter are not the ones in your disk, they are the ones you [upload to zookeeper](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+ZooKeeper+to+Manage+Configuration+Files).

You still usually have them locally on disk, but only cause you need them somewhere to upload them to zookeeper. I advise you first understand well what does mean using Solrcloud before trying to run a Solrcloud setup.

Comment: could you tell me where to put db-data-config and solrconfig files.As i understand this command ./server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost <Node1 IP>:2181 -cmd upconfig -confname renametoyourname_configs -confdir solr5.x.x/server/solr/configsets/<renametoyourname_configs>/conf upload the conf folder in zookeeper.But did not find this folder anywhere in zookeeper.pls guide me thanks.